# How to change float div order without any change in html?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 float Divs in the following order.

(1) (2) (3)

And I want to change the order of the Divs as following

(2) (1) (3)

Please guide me how can I achieve this?

[Fiddle Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/u7psuzor/)

**Code:**

```
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>


div{
   height:50px;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:50px;
}
.div1{width:50%; background:red; float:left;}
.div2{width:40%; background:yellow; float:left;}
.div3{width:10%; background:green; float:left;}
```

Comment: you can use jquery to dynamically insert innerHTML.

Comment: flex model & order is an easy option too for young browsers ;) http://jsfiddle.net/u7psuzor/10/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this type of coding

```
.div1{width:50%; background:red; display:inline-block;}
.div2{width:40%; background:yellow; float:left;}
.div3{width:10%; background:green; float:right}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7psuzor/3/

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds!! +1

Comment: On my screen this doesn't appear to match what he wants? I'm guessing he wants them all in line as 2 1 3, see this tinypic of how yours shows up on my screen.. http://tinypic.com/r/jzve5u/8

Comment: @user2985995, that's in chrome. you can adjust width to fix it

Comment: It's not really a valid answer then is it? If it doesn't work in all web browsers

Comment: @user2985995, that is to ask the company who made the browser. It's never going to work in all browsers because not all of them support all functions...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using position: absolute along with left percentage properties like follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/u7psuzor/8/

```
div {
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}

.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    left: 40%;
}
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width:40%;
    background:yellow;
    left: 0%
}
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    width:10%;
    background:green;
    left: 90%;
}
```

Comment: But why use float then?

Comment: My bad, forgot to crop that out, it has no effect on the output, will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do using jquery

```
$('.div1').insertAfter('.div2');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/u7psuzor/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
.div1{width:50%; background:red; position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
.div2{width:40%; background:yellow; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
.div3{width:10%; background:green; position:absolute; left:40%; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery we can

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $( ".div1" ).attr('class','divTemp');
  $( ".div2" ).attr('class','div1');    
  $( ".divTemp" ).attr('class','div2');    
})
```

Comment: This is enough if you use jquery `$('.div1').insertAfter('.div2');` why do you wanna make it more complecated

Comment: yes, but I dint use it before. hereafter I will use it insertAfter